# How to sort a list by an attribute of its child object?

Tags: java

I have the following objects in my springboot project.

```
Student {

  private String studentId;
  private Date courseStartedDate;
  private List<Course> course;

  public Date getCourseStartedDate() {
    return courseStartedDate;
  }

  public void setCourseStartedDate(Date courseStartedDate) {
    this.courseStartedDate = courseStartedDate;
  }

  public List<Course> getCourse() {
    return course;
  }

  public void setCourse(List<Course> course) {
    this.course = course;
  }
}

Course{

  private String courseId;
  private CourseStatus courseStatus;

  public CourseStatus getCourseStatus() {
    return courseStatus;
  }

  public void setCourseStatus(CourseStatus courseStatus) {
    this.courseStatus = courseStatus;
  }
 }

public Enum CourseStatus{

  BEGINNER("beginner");

  INTERMEDIATE("intermediate");

  ADVANCED("advanced");

  private String CourseStatus;

  CourseStatus(String courseStatus) {
    this.courseStatus = courseStatus;
  }

  public String getCourseStatus() {
    return courseStatus;
  } 
}
```

I have a list of students which I want to sort in descending order of `courseStartedDate` and `CourseStatus`.

I cannot modify the model.

I can sort the list by `courseStartedDate` as follows:
  `studentList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getCourseStartedDate).reversed());`

I am not sure how to modify the above line of code to sort the list based on `CourseStatus` as well?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Implement `Comparable` in `CourseStatus`

Comment: @rkosegi Is it not possible for me to use thenComparing method directly?

Comment: Student has a `List<Course> course` so how can you compare between them.

Comment: @rkosegi An `enum` is automatically `Comparable`, since it extends [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

Comment: Since a student has multiple courses, and each course has it's own status, that means a student has multiple (potentially differing) course statuses, so which course status should the student be sorted by?

Comment: @Andreas Beginner, Intermediate and Advanced is the order I am looking for

Comment: @SkyBlue So John and Bob both started courses at the same time. John is taking "Programming 101 (Beginner)" and "Rocket Science (Advanced)", while Bob is taking "Biology (Intermediate)". How should they be sorted? John has two different course statuses.

Comment: @Andreas First course in the list of his courses can be considered his primary subject. John -Beginner, Bob-Intermediate

Comment: @SkyBlue That's a *very* important piece of information, without which your question makes no sense, so you need to **edit** the question to clarify it with this extra rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarification from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732944/how-to-sort-a-list-by-an-attribute-of-its-child-object?noredirect=1#comment92392114_52732944):

> First course in the list of his courses can be considered his primary subject.

Since `CourseStatus` is an `enum` (not `Enum`), it is automatically `Comparable`, so to add a secondary sort order by status, you call [`thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-):

```
// ORDER BY courseStartedDate DESC, course[0].courseStatus DESC
studentList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getCourseStartedDate)
                           .thenComparing(s -> s.getCourse().get(0).getCourseStatus())
                           .reversed());
```

Or, if you want to sort the status in ascending order:

```
// ORDER BY courseStartedDate DESC, course[0].courseStatus ASC
studentList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getCourseStartedDate)
                           .reversed()
                           .thenComparing(s -> s.getCourse().get(0).getCourseStatus()));
```

Comment: I would never rely on the natural ordering of an enum for sorting. Someone will come along and say "hey, these constants would look much nicer in alphabetical order!" and break everything.

Comment: @Michael Then someone is an idiot. Enums implement `Comparable` and the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo-E-) method of the `enum` superclass [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) is `final`, so it cannot be changed, and the documentation specifically states that *"the natural order [of enum] is the order in which the constants are declared"*. If, however, you *are* surrounded by idiots, you could leave a comment, but a true idiot will mess it up, even if you add explicit order value to the enum.

Comment: I'm well aware of how it's implemented and that the behaviour is documented. Just as you should not rely on the ordinal directly (the documentation says it's only really for highly optimized implementations like EnumSet), it is not a good idea to rely on it indirectly either. You wouldn't rely on the order of declaration of fields anywhere else in your code, so it doesn't make sense to do it for enums either.

Comment: @Michael Why not? Unlike fields, the order of enum values is well-defined, e.g. `values()`: *"Returns an array containing the constants of this enum type, **in the order they're declared**"*.

Comment: The fact that enum has consistent behaviour by keeping constants in the order they're declared is not an argument for it being a good idea to rely on that behaviour. `Class.getAnnotatedInterfaces` guarantees that the interfaces are returned in their declared order. Would you rely on that as well?